# How To Send ArrayList From Activity To another?

Tags: java, android-intent, arraylist

In `MainActivity.java`

```
private static List<Film> filmList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And I have `FilmActivity.java`

I using Intent and i want to send `filmList` to `FilmActivity.java` 
I tried to use `putParcelableArrayListExtra()`

But it gave me an error. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish and include specific code that allows us to replicate your issue. When you post your code, please include the smallest amount of code that will still run and show the problem you're experiencing. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think your Film Class needs to implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and the error should disappear:)

Answer (score 0):

you should use **public**  not **private**

**public** static List filmList = new ArrayList<>();